How to debug Triton Python, especially Triton-JIT compiler passes?
I would like to do the following:

Build triton Python (which run from Python script):

Into specific directory
Build all cpp files with debug symbol
LLVM which used by triton should also be built with debug symbols


Run a Python file to debug:

Related Python script
Called cpp functions or objects could be debugged by GDB



I have searched the internet but cannot find related tutorials or guidance; thus. I would like to ask if anyone knows how to do this.

Have you consulted the project's readme?

@metatoaster yes, I read the very simple readme and cannot find a way. It provide a simple command of pip install -e python which I ran failed. and actually I do not know where to put related parameters for it to build debug version of it

You should be checking out the "Install from source" section that I linked, and then keep reading down and find that you may need to check out the correct version of LLVM, build that, and go from there. Also for failures encountered, you will need to update your question to include the specific error message and specific steps you tried rather than vaguely stating something because we can't guess what you actually failed to do.

@metatoaster the command is indeed from the very beginning of "Install from source" section. The failure message is saying I need to install python-xyz, which I think is not important, since I do not want to install globally......

Use a virtualenv and you won't be installing globally. You do need to follow the instructions exactly, that pip install -e python line will install this python belonging to the checkout of their repo. You were wrong to "think is not important", you were indeed missing that critical package and ignoring instructions did not help you here.  This is why you need to state clearly what you did and what did not work, if it told you to "install python-xyz" but you didn't follow the instruction, you should have stated that in the question.

@metatoaster if I follow the instruction, I wouldn't be able to build a version with debug symbol, in which word, I cannot debug cpp files. furthermore, it will install related package into the directories I do not want to

You should look into the relevant section in the setup.py and find that setting environment variable DEBUG=1 may help ensure the debug build is enabled. You can't expect to be spoonfed when you haven't indicate that you've tried with the information that's available in the project. If you tell others that you are into debugging others will expect that you have a better idea on what needs to be done, like putting in the effort to understand what's already there.
